# Was Plato present at Socrates' trial?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-greece

According to Plato's version of Socrates's Apology, he was present at the trial. However, I could not find any other historical source which says he either was or wasn't at the trial.

Are there such sources? Is there an agreement among researchers today as to whether he was there or not?

Comment: There are effectively two primary sources, Plato and Xenophon.  Neither mentions the other as each concentrates on Socrates

Comment: Why not post an answer @Henry?

Comment: @yannis I have no idea what researchers today think

Comment: Can't prove a negative, but if there are definitely only two primary sources....

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_problem

Comment: @Henry Yes, these are the two main sources, so it's unlikely there is a consensus today as to whether he was there or not. But I think there are other sources as well, only less reliable and from later times. (For example, I think there is a text of the accusations against Socrates, written a few centuries later and supposedly copied from a reliable source available at the time, but also possibly copied from Xenophon).

Comment: See [Socrates: Three primary sources: Aristophanes, Xenophon, and Plato](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/socrates/#ThrPriSouAriXenPla) as well as the discussion of *Apology* in Thomas Brickhouse & Nicholas Smith, [Plato and the Trial of Socrates](https://books.google.it/books?id=UIiFAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2004)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you; it seems the bibliography of Stanford is also worth checking out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that there are no extant sources that corroborate Plato's claim to have been present at Socrates' trial. However, we also have nothing that contradicts it.

As others have already mentioned in the comments, our two main sources of information for Socrates' later life are [Plato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato) and [Xenophon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenophon). Both were disciples of Socrates, although neither mentions the other.

Other significant sources for details about the life of Socrates are [Aristophanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristophanes) and [Aristotle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotle) (although Aristotle was not a contemporary of Socrates). In addition, we have some surviving fragmentary works by  [Aeschines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeschines), [Antisthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisthenes), [Euclid of Megara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid_of_Megara), [Phaedo of Elis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaedo_of_Elis) and [Timon of Phlius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timon_of_Phlius). Sadly, none of these explicitly state whether Plato was present at the trial or not.

Of course, it is possible that there were further contemporary sources that do not survive, but in the absence of any evidence to the contrary I think most researchers accept that Plato was present at the trial. This is a particular aspect of the wider "[Socratic Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_problem)", and like many aspects of the historical Socrates corroborative evidence is hard to come by.

---

The *[Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/index.html)* contains an excellent article by 
[Debra Nails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debra_Nails) on [Socrates](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/socrates/#ThrPriSouAriXenPla) which includes an examination of the main sources for Socrates' life and also of his trial and execution.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Although in my opinion it is very odd to just assume he was there because there is no source to contradict it (especially when you consider the fact Plato had an interest in claiming he was there).